# ssl certificate doesn't work for www

Tags: ssl, apache2

Short Description:  http://example.com is properly redirected to https://example.com and loads.  http://www.example.com is not redirected to https://www.example.com.  Direct loading fails with a certificate error.

I installed an SSL certificate using certbot.  When I query certbot for the list of certificates, I get:

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com-0004
    Domains: example.com www.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-05-17 21:13:21+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/privkey.pem
```

In my Apache Config, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
</IfModule>
```

And in httpd-le-ssl.conf I have:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0004/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have two questions.  Why isn't the redirect for www working?  Why isn't the certificate being recognized for www?  Chrome tells me:

```
This server could not prove that it is www.ncprepswimming.com; 
its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

What's wrong with my certificate and my configuration?  The output from apachectl -S is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:76)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:76)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf:12)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1006)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1006)
         port 80 namevhost db.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1086)
                 alias www.db.example.com
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1092)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1099)
         port 80 namevhost svn.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1106)
                 alias www.svn.example.com
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the certificate offered up by visiting both www and the non-www URLs, you'll see that the www version is not using the same certificate. That should tell you that you likely have a duplicate / bad config somewhere pointing to an incorrect certificate.

The output of apachectl -S clearly shows multiple www.example.com configurations on port 443 (assuming obfuscation here is correct):

```
VirtualHost configuration:
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:76)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:76)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf:12)
```

You need to look at the configs for yourself to determine which is correct and which isn't but likely you'll just need to delete ssl.conf (or comment some lines out) and restart.

Comment: Looking in ssl.conf was the key.  It was pointing to other certificates about which I didn't know.  I changed ssl.conf to point to the correct certificates, and it is now working.